# Find the index for years in an array of text

Tags: python

I am going through an exercise:

> Write a script to read in a ﬁle and return an array which contains the index of all ﬁelds which could contain a date between 1900 and 2020. For instance,
>
> ```
> Although solar eclipses (Alpha et al. 1980) might be granular (Bethe & Gamow 2000), it is thought...
> ```
>
> should produce an array `[6, 13]`.

My thoughts:  There's a function np.argwhere which takes an array and returns the indices for which it is true, but these are integers embedded in a string so I don't see how I can use it.

I was using the following code but it doesn't work because the years are associated with a bracket term.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt("exercise.txt", str)
test = np.arange(1900,2021)
test = np.asarray(1900,2021, str)
print(test)
print(a)
mask = np.isin(a, test)
print(np.argwhere(mask == True))
```

Comment: I don't understand the exercise description. What do solar eclipses have to do with this? Also, can you provide a short snippet of `exercise.txt` so we know what we're working with?

Comment: What is the point of `test = np.arange(1900,2021)`, when you reassign `test` to a new value on the very next line?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Solar eclipses don't have anything to do with this problem.  Everything from `e.g.` through `thought...` is the sample text, which happens to contain the numbers `1980` and `2000` at positions 6 and 13.

Comment: Hello John.  I was using np.asarray to change the data type.  I had a feeling I could do it in one command but was not sure.  I am learning.  Sorry my code is not good.  That is why I am here.

You are right about the exercise. txt.  I just took it to be "Although solar eclipses (Alpha et al. 1980) might be granular (Bethe & Gamow 2000), it is thought"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a problem for *num*py.

```
import re

def get_indices(s):
    fields = s.split(' ')
    matches = (re.match(r'[^\d]*(\d{4})(?!\d)', x) for x in fields)
    years = ((i, int(m.group(1))) for i, m in enumerate(matches) if m is not None)
    return [i for i, x in years if 1900 <= x <= 2020]

with open('exercise.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(get_indices(line))
```

For example:

```
>>> get_indices('Although solar eclipses (Alpha et al. 1980) '
                'might be granular (Bethe & Gamow 2000)')
[6, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks Mateen.  I'll have to figure out how that works.   Thank you very much.  The exercise came after a session on numpy so I was trawling the numpy commands for a solution.  I think my code would have worked had the years not been associated with the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [25]: a = 'Although solar eclipses (Alpha et al. 1980) might be granular (Bethe & Gamow 2000)'
In [26]: b = [i for i, aa in enumerate(a.split()) if aa.strip(')').isnumeric()]
In [27]: b = [i for i in b if 1980 <= int(a.split()[i].strip(')')) <= 2020]
In [28]: b
Out[28]: [6, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks mamun.  I have two solutions to work through to figure out how they work.  Neither are obvious to me.  I have come across strip and isnumeric before but not i for i or enumerate.  Now I just have to find some time to go through this.